# Accessing the Stack Without Popping

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

How to read from stack without popping?
I tried this:

```
mov dx, [ss:sp]
```

and got an error:
"error: invalid effective address"

I'm using NASM and my program is 16-bit for DOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

16 bit addressing doesn't support `[sp]` you can only address using a limited combination of `bx`, `bp`, `si`, `di` and an displacement. That means you have to move `sp` to one of the aforementioned registers, the usual one being `bp` which even has the `ss` segment associated as default. Function prologue typically sets this up, so you can access your parameters and locals easily:

```
push bp
mov bp, sp
...
mov dx, [bp + displacement]
```